# How to use mysql CONVERT function in sequelize

Tags: javascript

I want to generate following query using **model.findAll();** function how to write code for it

Example Query : -
`` SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `orderDatabase`.`student_checkin` AS `StudentCheckin` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`checkin_datetime`, date)); ``

Comment: welcome to stack. Please share with us what you have already tried and provide sample code so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs for where clause with functions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-).

Try this for the where clause:

```
Student_checkin.findAll() {
    where: {
        Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('checkin_datetime'), 'date')
    }
}
```